# Format a Google Sheets cell in plaintext via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, plaintext

Using Google Apps Script, I want to set the format for a Google Sheets cell to plain text.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to show a date in the U.S. date format (MM/DD/YYYY). *[We can assume the locale in the OP's Google account is set to use DD/MM/YYYY, a more common date format. –Ed.]*

I create the string like this:

```
var thisDate = Utilities.formatDate (new Date (), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (). getSpreadsheetTimeZone (), "MM / d / yyyy");
```

... which returns the date in the U.S. format, *06/13/2012*, which is what I want. However, when I set the value of a cell to that string:

```
sheet.getRange (1, n). setValue (thisDate);
```

... the date is formatted into the cell according to my locale, *13/06/2012*, not the U.S. format.

The following operation also fails, because the date is returned in the standard format, not the U.S. format:

```
sheet.getRange (1, n). getValue () == "06/13/2012"
```

When the cell is formatted as plain text, and not a date, everything works fine.

So, my question is, how to format a cell using JavaScript.

Answer (score 50):

The other answer, to set the format to 'plain text' in javascript, doesn't work. However, this does:

```
sheet.getRange(1,n).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
```

So the magic value for formatting text programmatically is '@STRING@'!

Comment: FM. Does Google document this stuff anywhere?

Comment: I found that just '@' works as well. This link helps - http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2015/05/18/cell-number-formatting-with-google-apps-script/

Comment: @ is found in many example, but it doesn't work for me. However, this one does. Thanks, christian.

Answer (score 9):

A complement to Christian good answer :
I have noticed that if your target cell has already been set to text format (manually), setting a value with `range.setValue()`
that might not been interpreted as a text (like a date, or a number), will change automatically the number format.
So the good solution, if you want definitely to keep a text format is

> range.setValue("01293849847").numberFormat("@");

and not

> range.numberFormat("@").setValue("01293849847");

Answer (score 9):

*Another way to force the value to be saved as plain text:*

Prepend a quotation mark: **`'`**. This has no effect on displayed value and also by reading the value 
 back the quatation mark is not included.

```
let dateStr = '07-07-20017';
sheet.getRange(x, y).setValue("'" + dateStr);

let backStr = sheet.getRange(x, y).getValue();
assert(dateStr === backStr);
```

Comment: That's the easy one, thank you :)
Do we know if that's documented anywhere?

Comment: @mlvljr a little late, but to answer your question, leading apostrophes to format a cell as text has been around since the days of Lotus 1-2-3. I happen to still use Excel 2003, and you can find this in the documentation: https://i.imgur.com/1r6wwSl.png

Comment: @thdoan Appreciated (incl. the oldtimer info tidbit :) ). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the text of the plan did not fit. Document as soon as the cell gets something like a date, just format the cell.
Found a way not to create date)

```
var thisDate1 = Utilities.formatDate (new Date (), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (). getSpreadsheetTimeZone (), "MM//d//yyyy");
```

Sorry so late reply. All hands did not reach.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like below and it works as I expected.  My B column show correct zero filled 3 digit number (e.g., 004) and my C column shows correct zero filled 10 digit number (e.g., 0060000001) as texts.  I downloaded the file it converted to Excel as texts with the padded zeros.  I think it would do the trick with the Date as a text as well.

winSS.getRange("US!B2:B").setNumberFormat("000").setNumberFormat("@");
 winSS.getRange("US!C2:C").setNumberFormat("0000000000").setNumberFormat("@");