# Applying "Automatic" number formatting / number formatting reset

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

Is it possible to apply the 'Automatic' number format programmatically through GAS?  My issue is that as I write columns of numbers, Sheets seems to attempt to apply appropriate formatting, but gets it wrong sometimes. That is, particular small integers (1 sometimes) will be formatted as dates.  The range is being written in one `myRange.setValues()` method and I can't see any pattern to the mistakes and therefore don't see any way to prevent the surprise mis-formatting.

But, when I select the range in sheets and just click "Automatic" on the number format menu all returns to normal.  It doesn't help to click that upfront as the writing of data somehow resets the format.

Despite the long-winded intro, my question is very simple: how to programmatically apply "Automatic" number formatting.  I'm thinking this is very basic, especially since google and searches here have been no help.

My current fallback solution is to use [`myRange.setNumberFormat("0")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) as the format for the whole range. This is not ideal as some numbers are very large and are easier to read in scientific notation. There are also some text strings in the range, but these format properly regardless of format applied.  I also would prefer to avoid having to iterate through the data and test for values to determine the best format, when it's just a couple clicks in the user interface.

[image: 'Automatic' Number format.]

Comment: This is a really good question, and something that is definitely not documented. Closest I could find was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758913/format-a-google-sheets-cell-in-plaintext-via-apps-script which only really overs plain text.

Comment: Really appreciate the comment. I searched and searched on this for nearly a week thinking that I must be missing something obvious.  The only suspicion I have left is that "Automatic" formatting is the **absence** of any number formatting, but my efforts to assign `null` or `undefined` have been totally unsuccessful.
`myRange.setNumberFormat((typeof undefined)); // or just 'undefined'`
turns a cell with a `0` into: 'un301899fin189930' -- that is, it's parsing  `undefined` as a string and then _valiantly_ trying to format the cell as a date.(?)  Passing `null` throws a server error.

Comment: And if anyone else is wondering `myRange.setNumberFormat("");` does not work. It simply hides all numbers (and dates). Strings still show normally. Just like if you placed `""` into the custom number format box in the user interface.

Answer (score 8):

You can try `.setNumberFormat('General');`

Below is the example:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange("B:B").setNumberFormat("General");
```

Comment: I've verified that this works, so thank you for that.  Would really appreciate if any references or sources can be provided for this solution.  Would give me more confidence that it is going to remain part of the supported API and not break at some point in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble finding anything documented, and tried pretty much everything suggested previously (null, 'General', the "magic" format of '0.###############', etc., etc.).

In my particular case, I had ranges previously set to strict plain text, which then got replaced with a checkbox data validation. Anytime the box was checked it was converted to the text "TRUE" instead of remaining a checkbox. 'General' and the "magic" format functionally worked fine, but did not actually set the format back explicitly to "Automatic".

I finally decided, why not just try this:

```
range.setNumberFormat('Automatic');
```

And it worked. This really should be documented, but at least a little bit of common sense lead me to the answer regardless.

Answer (score 2):

I use `copyFormatToRange` to copy/apply Automatic format:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var source_cell = sheet.getRange("A1");//A1: cell having automatic format 
source_cell.copyFormatToRange(sheet,1,1,2,2);//copy format of cell A1 to cell A2
```

You can write an API that opens another spreadsheet, read any cell that having the automatic format.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetId);//Id of another spreadsheet
```

Then use `copyFormatToRange` to your wanted cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have dates in the range, the below solution appears to be the best available option (without resorting to an API-based solution):

```
myRange.setNumberFormat('0.###############');
```

A zero-point-15x'#' seems to be a 'magic' number format that will allow very large numbers to show as scientific notation and smaller integers and decimals to show in the 'standard' format pre-application of number formatting.  This is also the format that is returned for cells that contain non-dates formatted with the 'Automatic' selection in the user interface.

Adding or removing **even one** `#` will 'break the spell' and cause very large numbers to display in non-scientific notation.  I also tested changes before the decimal place, but leaving the 15x#:

Also functional:  `myRange.setNumberFormat('#,##0.###############');`

So there is some flexibility for prefixes.

Non-functional:  `myRange.setNumberFormat('#.###############');`

The `0` is evidently required.

And finally,

Non-functional:  `savegameRange.setNumberFormat('0.##############[red]');`

This turns numbers red, but breaks the 'magic' formatting. So no suffixes it appears.

---

Again, if you have dates in the range, this will not work as they will, not surprisingly, display as the underlying number.  And potentially more problematic (but totally understandable), the only way to return them to date form is manually applying a date format, assuming you know which cells 'were' dates.

Complete replication of 'Automatic' number formatting requires traversing the range to find dates and apply desired date format, but otherwise applying the 'magic' format. (My original dataset was a mix of numbers and strings, so the simple approach given above works.)

Comment: It's good to note that this will not set it to automatic to reader's looking for a Tl;Dr. I discovered this before i made my earlier comment. Hope someone can puzzle it out, or show proof of it being impossible.

Comment: Thanks. Hard to put yourself in others' shoes when writing. Updated to make more clear the limitations of the approach. The link you cited in your earlier comment was also interesting and led me to research more Java documentation on number formatting. There may be more answers there for particular situations, but I did not see any mention of a way to trigger automatic formatting in Java, in the hopes that the method would also work here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the format to default which is Automatic

```
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getDataRange().getA1Notation()).clearFormat();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having hard time getting to understand how to remove custom number formatting from cell before writing already localized value to it.

### Why default number format

Nice thing about default Sheets number format [image]is that it can adapt string formats:

```
function testValueWrite()
{
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  let stringLocalized = (1234.56).toLocaleString('en-US');

  // write to cell with default number formatting
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(stringLocalized);

}
```

Result:

[image]

Number format magically applied from `1,234.56` string:

[image]

The problem is, actually, that there is no way to **ensure** that cell number format is in default state.

### Lack of "delete custom number format" option

If there is custom number format already applied to cell, it seems impossible to remove / reset it to default, looking at possible `Range`'s clear functions list:

- [`Range.clear()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear) - doesn't clear custom number formatting (surprisingly?)
- [`Range.clearFormat()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearformat) - as stated in documentation, `This clears text formatting .., but does not reset any number formatting rules.`, and it actually doesn't clear number formatting

#### Trying get info from recording macro

I tried recorded macro to see what happens when you click `Format - Number - Automatic`, then I got this:

[image]

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('S6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('General');
};
```

But somehow `General` option applied to cell gives different result now:

```
function testValueWrite()
{
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  let stringLocalized = (1234.56).toLocaleString('en-US');

  // applying number format 'General' via Apps Script and checking result
  sheet.getRange('A2').setNumberFormat('General').setValue(stringLocalized);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Unexpectedly, number format is not applied anymore from localized string:

[image]

#### Trying to get number format from fresh sheet

Added new sheet manually and checked result of `getNumberFormat()`:

```
function testFreshSheetNumberFormat()
{
  // manually created sheet
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet13');

  // get default number fromat of A1 cell
  let defaultNumberFormat = sheet.getRange('A1').getNumberFormat();

  console.log(defaultNumberFormat);
}
```

Result:

[image]

But somehow default `0.###############` value applied as number format now not working:

```
function testValueWrite()
{
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  let stringLocalized = (1234.56).toLocaleString('en-US');

  // applying number format '0.###############' via Apps Script and checking result
  sheet.getRange('A3').setNumberFormat('0.###############').setValue(stringLocalized);
}
```

Result:

[image]