# Google Sheets Programmatically Apply Custom Currency Symbols Number Format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I would like to programatically apply a custom number format so that I can use custom currency symbols in my cells (such as for cryptocurrency) and keep them as numbers so that I can do math with them or chart the values.

I have looked at the following options already:

- If I use the spreadsheet function "CONCATENATE", I get a string and cannot do math or chart with the final value.
- Spreadsheet function TEXT() can get the number format to display how I want but not all custom currency symbols "work" - the following for instance turns the value into a text string and I cannot do math/charts with it.

Ex: `=TEXT(SUM(C5:C7),"Ƀ#,##0.00000000")`

reference on TEXT(): https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en

- If I create a custom function, say `format(cell)`, and use JS to add any text strings to the value, it's no longer a number type.

Ex: `function GBP(amt) { return '£' + parseFloat(amt).toFixed(2)); }`

This won't work either as resulting string is not a number:

`function BTC(amt) { return parseFloat('Ƀ' + parseFloat(amt).toFixed(2)); }`

- `setNumberFormat(format)` cannot be used in a custom function to be called via spreadsheet formulas.
- Copying another cells formatting? I also see this as a workaround but it looks really not efficient if I have to copy and paste formatting for every cell I want the proper formatting : [Applying "Automatic" number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042702/applying-automatic-number-formatting)
- Copying the values into another column just for conditional formatting and the original numbers only range used for maths/charting. This is more a workaround a not a clean solution.

In short, I just want to add custom currency symbols to my numbers and still be able to do math and charts with them. Does anyone know a working, direct way to do so via Google Apps Scripts or spreadsheet functions/menus?

Comment: Why not just Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format and supply `[$Ƀ]#,##0.00000000`?

Comment: `query` can do custom formatting without making it as text. You  could try using query instead of `text()` in sheets API.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach The reason I cannot do that is because the cell values are dynamic - the values are determined by a data validation drop down. So different values require different formats. Your method will give that cell a format to apply to all conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To programmatically apply a currency format to a single number and to keep it as a number in order to do arithmetic operations with it use [setNumberFormat(string)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)).

NOTES:

- A custom function can't be used to apply a number format as custom functions can't modified the cell format.
- Conditional Formatting doesn't apply number formatting
- The Google documentation doesn't include currency formats. They could be got from the Google Sheets UI. First set the desired currency format for a cell by clicking on Format > More Formats > More Currencies, the click on Format > More Formats > Custom Number Formats... and copy the format from the text box.

Example:

The setNumberFormat is a partially implemented Google Apps Script function that currently applies Pound sterling currency format (`[$£-809]#,##0.00`) or a default format (`#,##0.00`) . The test function is used to call it assigning 'Pound sterling' to the format parameter.

```
function test(){
  setNumberFormat('Pound sterling');
}

function setNumberFormat(format) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var numberFormat = '';
  try {
    switch (format){
      case 'Pound sterling':
        numberFormat = '[$£-809]#,##0.00';
        break;
      default:
        numberFormat = '#,##0.00';
        break;
    }
    range.setNumberFormat(numberFormat);
  } catch (e){
    throw new Error('There was an error: ' + e);
  }
}
```

Related Q&A

- [Set cell format to text with google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38490800/1595451)

References

- [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)
- [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)