# I can't understand timezone in Script/Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having a problem with timezone getting strange results.

I'm testing a small code on a brand new calendar.
I put a test event on Nov 07 2012 from 22:00 to 23:00.

```
function myFunction() {
  Logger.clear();
  var calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("foo@group.calendar.google.com");
  var now=new Date();
  Logger.log(calendar.getTimeZone());
  Logger.log(Session.getTimeZone());
  Logger.log(now.toISOString());
  Logger.log(now.toUTCString());
  Logger.log(calendar.getEventsForDay(now)[0].getStartTime());
}
```

and this is what I get running it at Nov 07, 00:29

```
Europe/Rome
Europe/Rome
2012-11-06T23:28:25.889Z
Tue, 06 Nov 2012 23:28:25 GMT
Wed Nov 07 13:00:00 PST 2012
```

I read an old blog post http://googleappsscript.blogspot.it/2011/03/demystifying-time-zones-in-apps-script_21.html but it doesn't help me.

How can I get the startdate in the timezone of the calendar (or in the timezone of the script) ?

Comment: You can't rely on the logger when showing date objects value, it (almost) always return PST values.  There are a lot of posts on that subject here and on the old google group forum... for example a search on this forum for 'time zone' returned [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756376/odd-issue-of-date-changing-in-script-output) among others

Answer (score 0):

When converting a Date to a String, the timezone used is that of the server. To ensure the String representation is in the desired timezone (in this case the script) you need to use the `Utilities.formatDate()` method, which is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate).